# Upgrade ruby version for Rubygems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am getting the error shown at the end while trying to install `rhc` program :

```
~$ sudo gem install rhc
    ERROR:  Error installing rhc:
        net-ssh requires Ruby version >= 2.0.

~/.gem/ruby$ ls
1.8

~$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/mypc/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/mypc/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /home/mypc/.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux/rubygems-integration/1.8
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.8
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all

~$ ruby -v
    ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

~$ sudo gem install net-ssh -v 2.9.2
   Fetching: net-ssh-2.9.2.gem (100%)
   Successfully installed net-ssh-2.9.2
   1 gem installed
   Installing ri documentation for net-ssh-2.9.2...
   Installing RDoc documentation for net-ssh-2.9.2... 

~$ sudo gem install rhc
ERROR:  Error installing rhc:
    net-ssh requires Ruby version >= 2.0.
```

Any idea please how may I solve that. Thank you.

Comment: you seem to have two rubies installed. get rid of the old version.

Comment: It looks like your `gem` command is using "some" other version of `ruby` than your plain `ruby -v`. Not quite sure how to solve this in your situation, but I would suggest using some ruby version manager like `rvm` or `rbenv` if you are having problems with different versions of `ruby`.

Comment: try to delete Gemfile.lock and after that run bundle install